# OffsetDateTime jsonFormat allowing two type of patterns

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am implementing app in Spring Boot. Using Jackson.

Is there anyway to specify JsonFormat for parsing two types of date like:

- `2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00`
- `2020-10-06T10:15:30`

My current field:

```
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
  private OffsetDateTime interval;
```

Do I have to somewhere specify some ObjectMapper in configuration?

I am retrieving this error:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Regards

Comment: Your pattern is missing the `T` between date and time... Make it `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` and try again. In `java.time` the pattern should even be `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"`, but I don't know if JPA can handle that.

Comment: It works for 2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00, but not for 2020-10-06T10:15:30

Comment: The latter input is lacking the offset of `+01:00`, you can try to make that one optional in the pattern (`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[Z]"`), but I don't think the result would always be a valid `OffsetDateTime`. If you are handling `String`s of such different formattings (important elements might be there or not), you will have to use different patterns. You cannot create an `OffsetDateTime` parsing a `String` that does not have/indicate an offset.

Comment: @Ernesto What offset should the `interval` value have if the input string does not specify a time zone offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse using a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional zone offset, so you need a custom `JsonDeserializer`:

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeOptionalZoneDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffsetId()
            .optionalEnd()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter();

    public OffsetDateTimeOptionalZoneDeserializer() { super(OffsetDateTime.class); }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(p.getText(), formatter);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
public class Test {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = OffsetDateTimeOptionalZoneDeserializer.class)
    private OffsetDateTime interval;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "[" +
                        "{ \"interval\": \"2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00\" }," +
                        "{ \"interval\": \"2020-10-06T10:15:30Z\" }," +
                        "{ \"interval\": \"2020-10-06T10:15:30\" }" +
                      "]";
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Test[] tests = mapper.readValue(json, Test[].class);
        for (Test t : tests)
            System.out.println(t.interval);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
2020-10-06T10:15:30+01:00
2020-10-06T10:15:30Z
2020-10-06T10:15:30Z
```